# excel vba fill column from N to 1

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a VBA code to autofill range A1:A10000 with numbers 10000 to 1 with step -1

```
For i = 10000 to 1 step -1
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1) = i
Next i
```

This simple code doesn't work. I can't find the solution

Comment: What about 10000 - (row number - 1) ? and run from cell A1 to A10000...

Comment: Does it really need to be VBA?

Comment: The fix is `Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value = 10000 - i + 1`. Note that the same also works for `For i = 1 To 10000`. But either way, it's too slow.

Comment: Do you really need VBA? You can do this with a formula: `A1:= =SEQUENCE(10000,,10000,-1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Public Sub CountBackwards()
    Dim i As Long, lngCounter As Long
    
    lngCounter = 10000

    For i = 1 To lngCounter
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1) = lngCounter - i + 1
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

### Fill Column With Consecutive Integers

- If you don't want to wait (you don't!), fill an array with the numbers and copy the array in one go to the worksheet.

```vb
Sub ColumnOfIntegers()

    Const SHEET_NAME As String = "Sheet1"
    Const FIRST_CELL As String = "A1"
    Const INTEGERS As Long = 10000
    Const DESCENDING As Boolean = True
    Const CLEAR_BELOW As Boolean = True
    
    Dim Data() As Long: ReDim Data(1 To INTEGERS, 1 To 1)
    
    Dim r As Long
    
    For r = 1 To INTEGERS
        Data(r, 1) = IIf(DESCENDING, INTEGERS - r + 1, r)
    Next r
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SHEET_NAME).Range(FIRST_CELL)
        .Resize(INTEGERS) = Data
        If CLEAR_BELOW Then
            .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row - INTEGERS + 1) _
                .Offset(INTEGERS).Clear
        End If
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility:

```
Sub FillDown()
    Range("A1").Value = 10000
    Range("A2").Value = 9999
    Range("A1:A2").AutoFill Range("A1:A10000")
End Sub
```